# Jquery menu Collapse Behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Jquery Menu Built Dynamically,
Each of the SubMenu List Items Contain an Anchor tag and Checkbox. 
When the anchor tag is clicked I am attaching a popover to it dynamically which contains a text area inside it.

The problem is when I click on the checkbox and then try to type something inside the textbox(inside popover) the submenu collapses.
This happens only when the checkbox is clicked and then the popover.

If the popovers are clicked before the check boxes, I am able to type in the Textbox withing the popover without the submenu s hiding.

I have already used

```
_closeOnDocumentClick: function (event) {
            return false;
        },
select: function (event) {
            // TODO: It should never be possible to not have an active item at this
            // point, but the tests don't trigger mouseenter before click.
            this.active = this.active || $(event.target).closest(".ui-menu-item");
            var ui = { item: this.active };
            if (!this.active.has(".ui-menu").length) {
                this.collapseAll(event, false);// i have passed false to prevent collapse
            }
            this._trigger("select", event, ui);
        }
```

to prevent submenu from hiding.

This works perfectly except for the check box scenario I have explained.
also, I have tried `stopPropogation` and `preventDefaults`.

Main UL :

```
 <ul style="width: 250px; display: block; top: 0px; left: 248.75px;" class="ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front" role="menu" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="zzzz" />
```

first Li

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" id="ui-id-4" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12 "><div class="col-sm-8 "><span class="lbl"> Loss of Vision</span> <a class="badge badge-info"  id="liId" style="background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221) !important; cursor: pointer;"><i style="vertical-align: middle;" class="fa fa-comment-o "></i></a></div><div class="col-sm-1 "><div class="checkbox "><label> <input type="checkbox" name="name" id="name" data-displayvalue="Hxxxx" class="ace" data-classattr="classattr" data-originalid="doid" data-originalvalue="originalval"> <span class="lbl"></span> </label></div></div><div class="col-sm-1 "><div class="checkbox"><label> <input type="checkbox" name="Ename" id="id2" data-displayvalue="xxx" class="ace" data-classattr="xxx" data-originalid="oid" data-originalvalue="xxxx"> <span class="lbl"></span> </label></div></div></div></div></li>
```

Comment: HTML is needed so we can discern the positions of all elements involved. And it would help immensely if you were to place the HTML, jQuery (, and CSS if possible). into a [mcve]

Comment: @zer00ne the html is little huge , can we have a private chat

Comment: this is the hierarchy  
ul->li>div>(anchor , checkbox) anchor binds the popover dynamically

Comment: No headers wrapped in `<h3>`? One `.ui-menu` and a couple of  `.ui-menu` no futher nested sub menus?

Comment: I will edit the question to add html

Comment: the li is the second lvl menu li , it has many li s following same pattern

Comment: *"... but the tests don't trigger mouseenter ..."* You have registered `mouseover` event somewhere?,,,I don't see it,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148507/discussion-between-redevi-and-zer00ne).

Comment: I have not registered any mouseenter events on the menu